# one server is not updating data in tungsten replicator correctly

Tags: mysql, tungsten-replicator

i am using tungsten replicator
i have 3 servers
all masters
i used following mysql configuration to avoid primary key violation
server 1:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

binlog_format = row
innodb-file-per-table=1
server-id=1
log-bin=mysql-bin
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT
max_allowed_packet=52M
innodb-thread-concurrency=0
default-storage-engine=innodb

auto-increment-offset = 1
auto-increment-increment = 10

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
sync_binlog=1
```

server 2

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

binlog_format = row
innodb-file-per-table=1
server-id=2
log-bin=mysql-bin
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT
max_allowed_packet=52M
innodb-thread-concurrency=0
default-storage-engine=innodb

auto-increment-offset = 2
auto-increment-increment = 10

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
sync_binlog=1
```

server 3

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

binlog_format = row
innodb-file-per-table=1
server-id=3
log-bin=mysql-bin
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT
max_allowed_packet=52M
innodb-thread-concurrency=0
default-storage-engine=innodb

auto-increment-offset = 3
auto-increment-increment = 10

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
sync_binlog=1
```

few days ago server3 suddenly restarted but replicator service and mysqld service did not restart that's why server 3 gone offline with some error

we restarted the mysqld and replicator service and make the server online by skipping some transaction by force.

after that now all servers/nodes in tungsten replicator status are showing online but server 2 is not getting all updates from other servers (1 and 3). but all updates in server 2 is propagating to other servers (1 and 3). but almost 50% updates work with huge delay.

it seems server 3 is working perfectly that stopped but server 2 is not working perfectly. server 2 only can send all updates to other servers but can't get all updates from other servers (one way update is working right now but opposite are not working properly but almost 50% updates work with huge delay).

can anyone please tell me what is the reason behind this and how to fix?

status:

```
cookbook/trepctl services
Processing services command...
NAME              VALUE
----              -----
appliedLastSeqno: 178188705
appliedLatency  : 0.931
role            : master
serviceName     : alpha
serviceType     : local
started         : true
state           : ONLINE
NAME              VALUE
----              -----
appliedLastSeqno: 178062709
appliedLatency  : 53.53
role            : slave
serviceName     : bravo
serviceType     : remote
started         : true
state           : ONLINE
NAME              VALUE
----              -----
appliedLastSeqno: 176098723
appliedLatency  : 0.851
role            : slave
serviceName     : charlie
serviceType     : remote
started         : true
state           : ONLINE
Finished services command...
```

anyone please help

Comment: my some more observation: update from server 3 is going to server 2 but update from server 1 is not going to server 2, that's why it seems almost 50% are failing. any idea?

Comment: my observation is not correct for all time. updates from both servers(1,3) are not going to server 2 all time. but working sometime i guess.